# how to focus through MenuFlyoutItem's Content while keyboard arrow(Down) navigation in UWP?

Tags: c#, uwp, uwp-xaml

Is there any way to focus through Content inside MenuFlyoutItem. I have MenuFlyout which has MenuFlyoutItem and inside the menuFlyoutItem ,i'm having a Listview containing three items(Hai,Hi,Bye). After opening MenuFlyout , when i click down Arrow , the focus goes to first item inside MenuFlyout. After that when i click downArrow , the focus didn't goes to listview inside MenuFlyoutItem.

What I'm trying to achieve is , whenever MenuflyoutItem has content(ListView or any Control type),i want keyboard focus navigation inside the listview items also. how to Achieve?

My sample Project Link ([KeyboardFocusNavigationSample](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1dosqS4tgs-cFuwFAe26S6ks7rO1lLlKR?usp=sharing))

Answer (score 0):

According to your code, I added the `ListView_Loaded` event and used the [Control.Focus(FocusState) Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.control.focus?view=winrt-22621) to set focus state after the control is loaded.

The effect is that after opening the MenuFlyout, the focus is on the first row of the listview.

```
    private void RelativePanel_PointerPressed(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        MenuFlyout menuflyout = new MenuFlyout { };

        //menuflyout.Items.Add(new MenuFlyoutItem { Text = "Prem", TabIndex = 0 });
        //MenuFlyoutItem item2 = new MenuFlyoutItem { Text = "Kumar" };
        //menuflyout.Items.Add(item2); ;


        RelativePanel panel = new RelativePanel();
        ListView listView = new ListView { };
        listView.ItemsSource = new List<string> { "Hai", "Hi", "Bye" };

        //add by junjie
        listView.Loaded += ListView_Loaded;
       
        panel.Children.Add(listView);

        MenuFlyoutItem menuFlyoutItem = new MenuFlyoutItem { Style = (Style)this.Resources["xx"], DataContext = new CustomMenuFlyoutItemModel(panel) };
        menuflyout.Items.Add(menuFlyoutItem);


        menuflyout.ShowAt(sender as RelativePanel);
        
    }


    private void ListView_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ListView listView =  sender as ListView;
        listView.SelectedIndex = 0;
        listView.Focus(FocusState.Programmatic);
    }
```

Comment: no !! you are setting the focus programatically !! what i'm asking was ,on arrow navigation,first i want the focus to menuflyoutItem and then to the content inside the menuflyoutItem and so on(It has to be Cycling inside the menuflyout)

Comment: According to your scenario, there should be no other workaround to achieve the navigation effect you want.